# Django CMS template inheriting from ancestor not recognizing placeholder

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm using Django CMS 3.0.13. I have a page connected to an App Hook that inherits its template from the nearest ancestor.

The ancestor template is not connected to an App Hook, and has a placeholder:

```
{# ancestor template #}
{% block content %}
    {% placeholder 'content' %}
{% endblock %}
```

The App Hook page was previously overriding this block to hide the content placeholder. Now, I need to enable this placeholder, so I removed the override and am greeted with:

> "content" placeholder not found in an apphook application. Please use a static placeholder instead.

I have tried:

- Re-Adding the override and changing the name of the placeholder:

  ```
  {% block content %}
      {% placeholder 'new_content' %}
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- Leaving the inheritance the same and calling super:

  ```
  {% block content %}
      {{ block.super }}
  {% endblock %}
  ```
- Deleting the page, re-adding it, setting the app hook and publishing.

All of which result in the same error. The only thing I have found that will resolve this is to add a specific page for the App Hook'ed page to `CMS_TEMPLATES`.

This is less than ideal. What can I do to work around this?

Comment: `placeholder` doesn't work in an app hooked page. You need to use `static_placeholder` if you're working with app hooked templates.

Comment: @marksweb Can you point me to the documentation that states that? Because I have other templates with placeholders on app hooked pages that work just fine.

Comment: If I add a reference to the app hooked page in `CMS_TEMPLATES` it works just fine. Very weird.

Comment: Ah, maybe adding it to `CMS_TEMPLATES` makes it work. I can't find the docs that I'm sure I've seen before now. Can you just confirm, are you trying to display the same placeholder content from the inherited template in your app hooked template?

Comment: No, this would be new content. I just wanted to use the same placeholder name for each. I ended up adding static placeholders, but I'd still like to understand the reason why.

Comment: I found it; http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how_to/templates.html#static-placeholder

Comment: Well I'll be damned :) I wonder why adding it to `CMS_TEMPLATES` seems to work around that statement? Oh well. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `placeholder` tag has to be used on pages directly tied to CMS pages. If your template is rendered via a django app, you need to use `static_placeholder`.

A `static_placeholder` can also be used to re-use the same content between templates e.g. a footer.

Docs on static placeholders in terms of their use within CMS pages and not external apps; http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how_to/templates.html#static-placeholder

Also, if you've not explored this, then take a look at the docs around placeholders in your apps. http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/how_to/placeholders.html

Using a `PlaceholderField` in your apps can lead to some cool app hooks which can take all your CMS plugins. Specifically I've made a news app with those that allows you to add/edit content via the toolbar, then have a `ListView` page for all the objects which renders out the placeholder fields in the corresponding `DetailView`.